# A number of ten different digits, divisible by 8, 9, 10, and 11

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-theory

Each of the digits 0 through 9 is used exactly once to create a ten-digit integer. Find the greatest ten-digit number which uses each digit once and is divisible by 8, 9, 10, and 11.

Comment: Also on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4377942/362967).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a multiple of 10

> The number must end with a 0.  So put it at the end.

For a multiple of 9

> The sum of digits must be a multiple of 9.  This is the case when using all digits 0 to 9.  So you don't need to worry about that.

For a multiple of 8

> The last 3 digits must form a multiple of 8.  Since the last digit is 0, the 2 digits before the 0 must be a multilpe of 4.

For a multiple of 11

> The sum of digits at odd positions minus the sum of digits at even positions must be a multiple of 11.  This requires some calculations.
>  Starting from 9876543210, the odd digits are 9,7,5,3,1 with sum 25.
>  The even digits are 8,6,4,2,0, summing to 20.
>  To get a multiple of 11, you can swap some digits to transfer 3 units to the odd digits.  This gives 25+3 = 28 for the odds, 20-3 = 17 for the evens, and 28-17 = 11.
>  The simplest swap (affecting the smallest digits) seems to be to swap the 1 and the 4.
>
>  This results in the number 9876513240.  Luckily, 240 is a multiple of 8.  (or 24 is a multiple of 4).

So the number is

> 9876513240.
>
>  One can verify easily that is is a multiple of 8, 9, 10 and 11.
>  It is even a multiple of all integers from 3 to 12, except 7.

Note

> Note that swapping 1 and 4 is only an educated guess.
>  To prove that this choice is optimal note that any permutation
>  that affects larger digits than 4 results in a smaller number.
>  So you only need to try permutations of digits 1,2,3,4 to see there is no better way to fix the multiple of 11.
>  Being a multiple of 8 means the number must terminate with
>  120, 320 or 240.  This reduces the number candidates from 24 to 6.